# Drag and drop not working in Gnome3 file manager, selects multiple files instead

Tags: gnome, nautilus

[image]

when I use mouse to click and drag it doesn't drag but selects multiple files instead.
I use latest stable arch with Wayland and Gnome.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found the problem, I unknowingly enabled the experimental new views option.  Disabling it fixed the issue.

[image]

Comment: Where is this setting located?

Comment: @PrameshBajracharya The setting is located in the Nautilus (aka Files) preferences (See [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/861333/how-to-open-nautilus-file-manager-preferences) how to find them)

Comment: @FossilBit thanks! Will be helpful for future users. :) I did a bit more googling and solved this by giving a one line command.

Comment: or via terminal: `gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.preferences use-experimental-views false`

Answer (score 2):

Switch to list view clicking on the button in the top right corner will enable drag and drop
the button is between the magnifier and the hamburger, next to the windows control
https://askubuntu.com/a/1041795/534946